# How to make kibana dashboard dynamic?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I would like to know how kibana dashboard can be made dynamic? I mean , each time data is posted into the es, i want the visualisation charts in kibana to reflect the new data.

Comment: it depends on how you configure your dashboard - if it queries the same index that gets new documents, it'll show them automatically.

Comment: Hey , yeah i had some issue in selecting the timeframe. It was my mistake.